# INSERT ALL without a select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hope someone can help me. I want to add many records into a table from a statement I build.
For example:

```
ProjectSQL = "INSERT ALL "
For each Proj in split(Request.Form("ShowProjects"))
  ProjectSQL = ProjectSQL & "  INTO proj_tbl (proj_id) VALUES ('" & Proj & "') "
Next
db.Execute ProjectSQL

The SQL is:
INSERT ALL 
  INTO proj_tbl (proj_id) VALUES ('45) 
  INTO proj_tbl (proj_id) VALUES ('56) 
  INTO proj_tbl (proj_id) VALUES ('92)
```

Oracle SQL wants a Select statement at the end.

I don't want to hammer the database with each loop because there could be many records to add (and the dba will cut off my balls).

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have to insert many rows, you have to insert many rows. There is no way to avoid it. I don't know which programming language you are using but e.g. Java/JDBC and other interface support batching of statements, maybe that is available in your programming language as well.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `proj_id` is a `number`, you could build a SQL statement like this that does a meaningless query from the `dual` table

```
INSERT ALL 
  INTO proj_tbl (proj_id) VALUES (45) 
  INTO proj_tbl (proj_id) VALUES (56) 
  INTO proj_tbl (proj_id) VALUES (92) 
  SELECT 1 FROM dual
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just build the statement as:

```
INSERT INTO proj_tbl(proj_id)
    select 45 from dual union all
    select 56 from dual union all
    select 92;
```